# How update/edit uploaded files in asp.net mvc 5 without redundancy?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, asp.net-mvc-5, updates

I have a problem with update data in `Asp.net MVC 5` with `Razor Engine` . 
my Update code works fine but I have some problems with it . When I update `Image` , old image stays in `Images folder`.  I want to delete old image if it changed . and I want to stay old image if it didn't change . 
How can I do it ? 
Thanks a lot for any help 
I don't know how write if statement for this :/

**CarouselRepositories.cs**

```
public bool Update(NP1.Models.Carousel entity, bool autoSave = true)
    {
        try
        {

            db.Carousels.Attach(entity);
            db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            if (autoSave)
                return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Admin controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditCarousel(int id)
    {

        var load = db.Carousels.Find(id);
        return View(load);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCarousel(Carousel carousel, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
    {
        CarouselRepositories blCarousel = new CarouselRepositories();
        string path = "";
        var fileName = "";
        var rondom = "";
        if (UploadImage != null)
        {

            fileName = Path.GetFileName(UploadImage.FileName);
            rondom = Guid.NewGuid() + fileName;
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                  Server.MapPath("~/Images/Carousel"), rondom);

            carousel.CarouselImage = rondom;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            UploadImage.SaveAs(path);
            carousel.CarouselImage = rondom;
            if (blCarousel.Update(carousel))
            {
                return JavaScript("alert('Carousel slide added');");
            }
            else
            {
                return JavaScript("alert('didn't add');");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return JavaScript("alert('Error');");
        }

    }
```

**EditCarousel.cshtml:**

```
@model NP1.Models.Carousel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "EditCarousel";
Layout = "~/Views/Admin/AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditCarousel", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "myUploadForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CarouselID)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarouselSubject, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarouselSubject)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarouselSubject)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarouselInfo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarouselInfo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarouselInfo)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarouselImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CarouselImage)*@
            @Html.ImageFor(model => model.CarouselImage, new {width="300"},"","Images","Carousel")
            @Html.Upload("UploadImage")
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CarouselImage)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Updated Amin Controller :**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCarousel(Carousel carousel, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
    {
        CarouselRepositories blCarousel = new CarouselRepositories();
        string path = "";
        var fileName = "";
        var rondom = "";
        if (UploadImage != null)
        {

            fileName = Path.GetFileName(UploadImage.FileName);
            rondom = Guid.NewGuid() + fileName;
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                  Server.MapPath("~/Images/Carousel"), rondom);

            carousel.CarouselImage = rondom;
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = carousel.CarouselImage;
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                  Server.MapPath("~/Images/Carousel"), fileName);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            UploadImage.SaveAs(path); // I got error in this line 
            carousel.CarouselImage = rondom;
            if (blCarousel.Update(carousel))
            {
                return JavaScript("alert('Carousel slide added');");
            }
            else
            {
                return JavaScript("alert('didn't add');");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return JavaScript("alert('Error');");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that if `UploadImage` is not `null` in the POST method, then you want to delete the existing image?

Comment: Yes , I want this . but I have another problem too . If `UploadImage` to be `null` I get error , I spend 2-3 days but I couldn't fix it . @StephenMuecke

Comment: Just delete the folder based on the FileName

Comment: Assuming the property `CarouselImage` contains the file name of the existing image, then its value will posted back (you have a hidden input for it) so its just a matter of deleting it (using `System.IO.File.Delete()`) before you call `UploadImage.SaveAs(path);` (or better, just use the existing file name so its overwritten)

Comment: And what is the error you get when `UploadImage` is `null`?

Comment: What's the error @shimaamini?

Comment: Thank you , @StephenMuecke I need a little time to implement your codes , thanks

Comment: I didn't get error for update @SirwanAfifi , I just have redundancy in uploaded images . by the way, a big error (bug) is in all of my `add codes` if there was any image to save , I couldn't show `validation message` for it and I can't save Null value for it :|

Comment: I do some changes and updated my post , it's very interesting `path `value  in `UploadImage.SaveAs(path);` is true , but gave me error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` @StephenMuecke

Comment: Could you plz take a look at my updated post ? @SirwanAfifi

Comment: Is the error only occurring when `UploadImage` is `null` or in both cases? If its `null` then `UploadImage.SaveAs(path)` would throw a NullReferenceException. You will want to enclose that line of code in an `if (UploadImage != null) { UploadImage.SaveAs(path) }`

Comment: Error occurs when `Uploadimage` is Null @StephenMuecke

Comment: So , How can I fix it ? Sorry for my low level questions , I'm new in programming  @StephenMuecke

Comment: OK , Thank you Dear @StephenMuecke :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete the current file if the value of `UploadImage` is not `null` in the POST method, then you can use the `System.IO.File.Delete` method

```
private const string _ImagesPath = "~/Images/Carousel";

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditCarousel(Carousel carousel, HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    CarouselRepositories blCarousel = new CarouselRepositories();
    if (UploadImage != null)
    {
      // Delete exiting file
      System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_ImagesPath), carousel.CarouselImage));
      // Save new file
      string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(UploadImage.FileName);
      string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_ImagesPath), fileName);
      UploadImage.SaveAs(path)
      carousel.CarouselImage = fileName;
    }
    if (blCarousel.Update(carousel))
    {
      ....
    }
    else
    {
      ....
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , and sorry I get `'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context` error in line `File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_ImagesPath)), carousel.CarouselImage);`

Comment: OK, you need to use `System.IO.File.Delete(....)` (you have 2 assemblies with classes named `File`)

Comment: I changed it , now it gave me this error `Delete takes 2 arguments` ! I have 2 arguments why this error occur ?!

Comment: No, You have a parenthesis in the wrong place based on you last comment (the double RHS parenthesis should be at the end) - `System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(_ImagesPath), carousel.CarouselImage));`

Comment: Thank you again , that error fixed , but  a new error occur! that's amazing . `http://localhost:35676/Admin/EditCarousel/28`  `The resource cannot be found.` !! :(

Comment: That suggests the `/Views/Admin/EditCarousel.cshtml` view does not exist - are you sure you do not have a typo somewhere?

Comment: Yes I'm sure , that url is true :(

Comment: To be sure, right click the mouse inside the GET method and click _Go To View_

Comment: I closed and open  my visual studio and it works now :| , every thing works fine now , my problems solved , a big thank you dear :)